# Application to show device status to users

Tags: ruby, web-services, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am developing an application that will show statuses (On or off) of different devices on user's dashboard . I believe i will have to do it through API calls , and get the current status of the devices connected to the LAN . I am looking forward to using the following gems -

Devise

Rolify

Cancan

ActiveAdmin (for Super user)

and Postgresql database .

I have been asked to make the API calls ,more secure so that no else can get hold of it (Reading upon it but not getting much idea how to move forward) . Any suggestions from someone who has already achieved the same or advice on how to go on doing it are more than welcome . Looking forward to some useful replies . The project is still in the starting phase and i want to make sure that i am proceeding in the right direction .